# typescript 3.0 and react defaultProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript

If I have a prop defined like this:

```
interface Props {
  Layout?: LayoutComponent;
}
```

Then if I supply defaultProps on on a `ClassComponent`:

```
class MyComp extends React.Component<Props> {
  static defaultProps: Pick<Props, 'Layout'> = {
    Layout: ({ children }) => <>{children}</>
  };
}
```

Typescript does not pickup the fact that it cannot be undefined:

```
render() {
    const { previousLocation, data } = this.state;
    const { location, Layout } = this.props;
    const initialData = this.prefetcherCache[location.pathname] || data;

    return (
      <Layout> // JSX element type 'Layout' does not have any construct or call signatures.
        <Switch>
```

It should never be undefined because of the `defaultProps`.  Typescript does not pick this up.

Is there anyway of letting the compiler know that it cannot be undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR do not define `Layout` prop as optional, typescript will handle it on its own.

Internally `Layout` prop shouldn't be optional as it is always defined due to the `defaultProps`:

```
interface Props {
  Layout: LayoutComponent;
}
```

For external users any prop that has a default prop is transformed to be optional by [`LibraryManagedAttributes`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L2312)

> This helper type defines a transformation on the component's Props type, before using to check a JSX expression targeting it; thus allowing customization like: how conflicts between provided props and inferred props are handled, how inferences are mapped, how optionality is handled, and how inferences from differing places should be combined