# LibraryManagedAttributes not mapping element type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, definitelytyped

I have the following component:

```
interface LayoutProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

type LayoutComponent = React.ComponentType<LayoutProps>;

interface RootProps {
  Layout?: LayoutComponent;
}

class Root extends React.Component<RootProps> {
  static defaultProps: Pick<RootProps, 'Layout'> = {
    Layout: ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => <>{children}</>
  };

  render() {
    const { Layout, children } = this.props;
    return (
      <Layout>  // when optional errors with JSX element type 'Layout' does not have any construct or call signatures.
        {children}
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Root>Foobar</Root>, document.getElementById('mount-node'));
```

typescript does not pick up the fact that there is a `defaultProp` for `Layout` which I thought it would due to the new [LibraryManagedAttributes](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L2312) mapped type.

I am using `@types/react@16.4.14` and typescript `3.0.3`.

Typescript complains about `Layout` not being callable when I thought that the whole point was the defaultProp would be mapped.

If I add this code, then it is fine:

```
  render() {
    const { Layout, children } = this.props;

    if (!Layout) {
      return null;
    }

    return <Layout>{children}</Layout>;
  }
```

I have `strictNullChecks` set to true.

Comment: If the error you're getting is _JSX element type 'Layout' does not have any construct or call signatures._  - it is not related to prop being defined or not. It is about the typing of the prop. I bet it should be `Layout: typeof LayoutComponent;`

Comment: @AlekseyL. I think it is because it is undefined, `LayoutComponent` is a type `export type LayoutComponent = React.ComponentType<LayoutProps>;`

Comment: @dagda1 I attempted to add the missing parts to the code snippet and I don't get a `JSX element type 'Layout' does not have any construct or call signatures` error.  What error are you getting?  Please make sure the code in the question is sufficient for you to reproduce the error.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I have added a full example which illustrates the problem

Comment: [As previously answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52453550), `RootProps.Layout` should not be declared as optional.  When I make that change, I am left with no errors.